# How to read data from MongoDb using Spark?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read data from MongoDb using [MongoDb spark connector](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/). I can print the schema using Spark but when I try to show data, it gives me the below error. I have tried to pass all the partitioner options but did not get success.

What can be the possible reason?

**Details**:

> Spark Version - 3.3.0
>
> MongoDb version - 5.5.0
>
> Connector Jar - [Link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.13/10.2.0)

**SPARK Code (Giving Partition level error)**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(job_name).getOrCreate()
url = "mongodb://ReadUser:Password123@mongo-db.test.app:27017/db_name"
df = (
    spark
    .read
    .format("mongodb")
    .option('connection.uri',url)
    .option("database", "db_name")
    .option("collection","collection1")
    .option('partitioner','com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.partitioner.ShardedPartitioner')
    .load()
)
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

I have also tried to execute the code using Python (to check the permission) and I can read data from that.

**Python Code (Working Fine)**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
url = "mongodb://ReadUser:Password123@mongo-db.test.app:27017/db_name"
client=MongoClient(url)
db=client["db_name"]
table = db["collection1"]
x = table.find()
for data in x:
    print(data)
```

**Spark Error Log**

> com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.exceptions.MongoSparkException: Partitioning failed.

```
    root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- created_date: double (nullable = true)
 |-- code: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- expiry_time: double (nullable = true)
 |-- mail_res: void (nullable = true)
 |-- noOf_code: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- proposalId: void (nullable = true)
 |-- code_s: void (nullable = true)
 |-- twillow_res: void (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)

An error occurred while calling o118.showString.
: com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.exceptions.MongoSparkException: Partitioning failed.
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.partitioner.PartitionerHelper.generatePartitions(PartitionerHelper.java:69)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.MongoBatch.planInputPartitions(MongoBatch.java:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.BatchScanExec.inputPartitions$lzycompute(BatchScanExec.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.BatchScanExec.inputPartitions(BatchScanExec.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExecBase.supportsColumnar(DataSourceV2ScanExecBase.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2ScanExecBase.supportsColumnar$(DataSourceV2ScanExecBase.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.BatchScanExec.supportsColumnar(BatchScanExec.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Strategy.apply(DataSourceV2Strategy.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$1(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies.plan(SparkStrategies.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$3(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$folder$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:196)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$folder$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:199)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:192)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.$anonfun$plan$2(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkStrategies.plan(SparkStrategies.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.createSparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:495)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$sparkPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:552)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:552)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$writePlans$5(QueryExecution.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$.append(QueryPlan.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.writePlans(QueryExecution.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$explainString(QueryExecution.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.explainString(QueryExecution.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$7(SQLExecution.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3920)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2904)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:329)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 with name 'Unauthorized' and error message 'not authorized on config to execute command { find: "collections", filter: { _id: "db_name.collection1" }, projection: { _id: 1, timestamp: 1, uuid: 1, dropped: 1, key: 1 }, limit: 1, singleBatch: true, $db: "config", lsid: { id: UUID("a835c704-429c-4b0e-99f7-739d28105be3") } }' on server mongo-db.test.app:27017
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.lambda$execute$1(FindOperation.java:699)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$2(OperationHelper.java:566)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:591)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$3(OperationHelper.java:565)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:591)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSourceAndConnection(OperationHelper.java:564)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.lambda$execute$2(FindOperation.java:690)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingSyncSupplier.get(RetryingSyncSupplier.java:65)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:722)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:191)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:213)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.partitioner.ShardedPartitioner.lambda$generatePartitions$0(ShardedPartitioner.java:93)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.config.AbstractMongoConfig.withClient(AbstractMongoConfig.java:147)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.config.ReadConfig.withClient(ReadConfig.java:45)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.partitioner.ShardedPartitioner.generatePartitions(ShardedPartitioner.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.partitioner.PartitionerHelper.generatePartitions(PartitionerHelper.java:54)
    ... 78 more
```

Comment: Not an expert on MongoDB, but perhaps `ReadUser` (used by `ShardedPartitioner`) does not have permissions to read "config" to figure out shard configuration? Can you remove     `.option('partitioner','...')` and try?

Comment: I have already removed and tried it ... shared is one of the types that spark support. I have tried all the types and also without any partitioner. But getting the same issue.

Comment: Can you use some super-user instead of this `ReadUser`? That way you can be sure that it's a permissions/grants issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your spark session like this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName(job_name) \
    .master(master) \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "value") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "value") \
    .getOrCreate()
```